# Vulkan physical device selection causes memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, vulkan

Currently using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, g++11.1.0, C++20, SDL2

Compiler Flags: `-lvulkan -ldl -lSDL2main -lSDL2`

Code:

```
#include "VkBootstrap.h"

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_vulkan.h>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    VkExtent2D windowExtent {1600, 900};

    // Initialize SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to initialize SDL: " << SDL_GetError();
        std::abort();
    }

    // Create a SDL Window
    SDL_Window* window {SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Vulkan",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        windowExtent.width,
        windowExtent.height,
        SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE
    )};

    // Check if window was created sucessfully
    if (!window)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create SDL Window: " << SDL_GetError();
        std::abort();
    }

    vkb::InstanceBuilder instanceBuilder {};

    // Initialize the Vulkan instance, with basic debug features
    auto builderResult {instanceBuilder
        .set_app_name("Vulkan Game")
    .request_validation_layers(true)
        .use_default_debug_messenger()
    .require_api_version(1, 2, 0)
    .build()};

    vkb::Instance vkbInstance {builderResult.value()};

    // Store the Instance
    VkInstance instance {vkbInstance.instance};

    // Store the Debug Messenger
    VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT debugMessenger {vkbInstance.debug_messenger};

    VkSurfaceKHR surface {};

    // Get a Vulkan Rendering Surface of the SDL Window
    if (!SDL_Vulkan_CreateSurface(window, instance, &surface))
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to Create Vulkan Rendering Surface.\n";
        std::abort();
    }

    vkb::PhysicalDeviceSelector gpuSelector {vkbInstance};

    // Initialize the Physical Device with a GPU that can render to the window
    vkb::PhysicalDevice vkbPhysicalDevice {gpuSelector
    .set_minimum_version(1, 2)
    .set_surface(surface)
    .select()
    .value()};
    
    // Store the Vulkan Physical Device
    VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice {vkbPhysicalDevice.physical_device};

    // Surface Deletion
    vkDestroySurfaceKHR(instance, surface, nullptr);

    // Debug Messenger Deletion
    vkb::destroy_debug_utils_messenger(instance, debugMessenger);

    // Instance Deletion
    vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);

    // Window Deletion
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
}
```

Driver:
[image]

Following the tutorial https://vkguide.dev/ and using the VkBootstrap library, when I try to select the physical device, it causes a memory leak like the one shown below:

```
=================================================================
==44934==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 576 byte(s) in 4 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f8e9c905e17 in __interceptor_calloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:154
    #1 0x7f8e97a13a1d  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2+0x4a1d)
    #2 0x31647261632e  (<unknown module>)

Direct leak of 128 byte(s) in 4 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f8e9c905c47 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cpp:145
    #1 0x7f8e9b35a0c5  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1+0xe0c5)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 704 byte(s) leaked in 8 allocation(s).
```

I ran a diagnostic on the available GPUs by modifying the VkBootstrap.cpp file to output data, and got this:

```
GPU: Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
Api Version: 4202641
Device ID: 6418
Device Type: 1
Driver Version: 88080387


GPU: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0, 256 bits)
Api Version: 4194306
Device ID: 0
Device Type: 4
Driver Version: 1


Selected GPU: Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
```

Although I have an Nvidia and Intel graphics card, how come it isn't showing the Nvidia graphics card as a viable GPU?

Also, why are these memory leaks occurring? How can I resolve them?